# How to connect the audio to bluetooth when playing using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am playing the audio from an url using AVPlayer, but when the iPhone is connected to a Bluetooth device it is not playing via Bluetooth, how to play via Bluetooth if it is connected, i see some posts in SO, but none of those are clearly explained. Below is my code.

```
    -(void)playselectedsong{

    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    self.songPlayer = player;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[songPlayer currentItem]];
    [self.songPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self.songPlayer play];

}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == songPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");


        } else if (songPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
    }
}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

 //  code here to play next sound file

}
```

Comment: Do you mean it's not playing via Bluetooth at all, or it doesn't play over Bluetooth when you switch from speaker to Bluetooth while the song is being played?

Comment: @MDB983: Its not playing via Bluetooth at all.

Comment: @MDB983: Any idea on the issue, please help me out.

Comment: I found this post. It may helps to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482608/ios-avplayer-control-using-bluetooth?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                         sizeof(sessionCategory),&sessionCategory);

// Set AudioSession
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&sessionError];

UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

Comment: @PoojaSrivastava write this code in this method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" of this file "AppDelegate.m".

note:- write this code before this line "[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
".

Comment: "You can set AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth option only if the audio session category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord."
Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptionallowbluetooth?language=objc

Answer (score 10):

**For Swift 3.1**

Short version:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, with: [.allowBluetooth])
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
    fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
}
```

Extended version to be sure, that you're using correct input:

```
/**
    Check availability of recording and setups audio session
    with prioritized input.
 */
func setupSessionForRecording() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, with: [.allowBluetooth])
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
    }
    var inputsPriority: [(type: String, input: AVAudioSessionPortDescription?)] = [
        (AVAudioSessionPortLineIn, nil),
        (AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic, nil),
        (AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP, nil),
        (AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio, nil),
        (AVAudioSessionPortCarAudio, nil),
        (AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic, nil),
    ]
    for availableInput in audioSession.availableInputs! {
        guard let index = inputsPriority.index(where: { $0.type == availableInput.portType }) else { continue }
        inputsPriority[index].input = availableInput
    }
    guard let input = inputsPriority.filter({ $0.input != nil }).first?.input else {
        fatalError("No Available Ports For Recording")
    }
    do {
        try audioSession.setPreferredInput(input)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
    }
}

/**
    Check availability of playing audio and setups audio session
    with mixing audio.
 */
func setupSessionForPlaying() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [.mixWithOthers])
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
    }
}
```

The main idea that you have 2 functions for changing audio session settings. Use `setupSessionForRecording` right before recording, and `setupSessionForPlaying` before playing audio.

**Important** to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`, but not `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, because of it's buggy. Use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` only if you really need to play and record audio same time.

Comment: Tried the above code and looked for almost every solution online. Everything is set correctly. But the bluetooth headset input/output is just not being taken by the app. The phone mic also stops as the input gets successfully set to bluetoothHFP, but when you speak, it doesn't catch. wired headsets work perfectly though. The same bluetooth headset works perfectly with Siri. Is there some other configuration setting that I am missing - like permissions or capabilities? 

Device used : iphone 5c (10.3.2)

Comment: @SayaleePote Did you try to set AV category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`?

Comment: Yes it was set to PlayAndRecord earlier. Didn't work. Then I set it separately as suggested here. Still no success.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a category and options on the `AVAudioSession`.

Try this when the app starts:

```
//configure audio session
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL setCategorySuccess = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                           setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                           withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                           error:&setCategoryError];

if (setCategorySuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Session options set.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"WARNING: Could not set audio session options.");
}
```