# AVAudioSession not detecting connected bluetooth device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, avaudioplayer

I am using the following code to detect available outputs and it isn't picking up my connected bluetooth device. I know that my bluetooth device is properly connected because I am playing music from it.

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        for description in session.currentRoute.outputs {
            if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {
                NSLog("headphone plugged in")
                let alertActin = UIAlertAction(title: "Headphones", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                alertActin.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")
                alert.addAction(alertActin)
            } else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP {
                NSLog("Bluetooth plugged in")

                let alertActin = UIAlertAction(title: description.portName, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                alertActin.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")
                alert.addAction(alertActin)
            } else if description.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE {
                NSLog("Bluetooth plugged in")

                let alertActin = UIAlertAction(title: description.portName, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                alertActin.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "titleTextColor")
                alert.addAction(alertActin)
            }
            else {
                NSLog("")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to instruct AVAudioSession to allow Bluetooth outputs first as suggested [here](http://devmonologue.com/ios/tutorials/avaudiosession-bluetooth-support/).

Note that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44247378/7034621) discurages use of AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and recommends using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback when working with output devices.

Comment: I added this to my code but my bluetooth speakers still aren't appearing do {
   try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.allowBluetooth])
   try session.setActive(true)
  } catch {
   fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
  }