# How to communicate between Bluetooth Speaker and iOS Phone?

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

I need help for following issue.
I have developed iOS music app recently.
But when I play a music file on my app after my phone connect with Bluetooth speaker on my car, the music don't play on Bluetooth speaker.
Of course, the music play on my app well.
I don't understand what is problem.

Please help me.

Best Regards,
Vitaly.

Comment: Have you checked this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133636/how-to-connect-the-audio-to-bluetooth-when-playing-using-avplayer

Comment: Try playing audio from another app. Is it playing ?

Comment: Yes. it is playing from another app.

Comment: Please post some code